# Community builder - Why do I have to setup differently my links?

Tags: sandbox, custom-link

I'm building a SF community with different pages ;
Sandboxes are dev5 and dev5.

Let's take mentionLegales page, that's how it is defined in dev :

[image]

Same in dev6 :

[image]

But the href attribute's to reference pages are different in the orgs,

Dev5 (that works) :

```
<a href="../s/mentionslegales">Mentions légales | </a>
```

Dev6 (works) :

```
<a href="../mentionslegales">Mentions légales | </a>
```

Why do I have to add the /s in dev5 ?
What does it mean ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

Custom Url's in dev 5 :
[image]

Custom Url's in dev 6 :

[image]

Comment: As per this idea, [Communities - Custom URLs has '/s' path which can't be removed](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cKd5AAE), does your force.com site related to community on DEV has any custom URL with `/s`?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm editing my question !